# Is "type" a reserved keyword in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.6.x

If I define the following struct like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
  uint256 type;
}
```

The Solidity compiler throws an error:

> Expected identifier but got 'type'

I checked to have no mistake in my code and, when changing "type" with anything else, the error goes away.

Is "type" reserved in Solidity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `type` is a reserved keyword in Solidity, according to [the source code](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/2410f0ed5a47cf262a2d836f4c493c48e8bd9977/liblangutil/Token.h#L190).

However, according to [the docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.5/miscellaneous.html#reserved-keywords), `type` is *not* a reserved keyword.

With that said, the reason it is reserved is for deriving type information on-chain. You can read more about it [in the docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.9/units-and-global-variables.html#type-information):

> The expression `type(X)` can be used to retrieve information about the type `X`. Currently, there is limited support for this feature (`X` can be either a contract or an integer type) but it might be expanded in the future.

Edit: I would expect the error you received to read:
`ParserError: Expected identifier but got reserved keyword 'type'`. This seems like a bug that should be resolved so that future developers do not have this issue as well.